# SSRS Enter the Product Key Locks Up

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, license-key

We have SQL Server 2019 RTM Standard Edition (64-bit) installed. I'm now installing Reporting Services, but it won't accept the product key. The SQL Server install is on an AWS EC2 and we selected SQL Server as part of the vm, so it came "installed" on the vm. I'm now trying to install Reporting Services. I used Powershell to extract the product key from the registry because when I ran sql server installer, it did not show the product key for the default instance that is running. If getting the DigitalProductID from the registry isn't the correct key, then how do we find the correct one to get reporting services out of evaluation mode?

Comment: I'm having the same issue wanting to install Reporting Services with my AWS EC2 "Windows Server 2022 with SQL Server Standard" instance.

Answer (score 0):

The product activation key (PID) is stored on the installation media in: `\x64\DefaultSetup.ini`

Comment: That is the issue. The installation media doesn't show the key when the installer is run. That is why I extracted the key from the registry.